# Magento 1.9 Illegal scheme supplied

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login

Hey I've started getting this error yesterday:

```
"Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted"
```

The error started after we implemented this fix for Varnish cache. [Caracter fix](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/114)

First I did, disabled the Complination manually.

Then went to phpMyadmin and checked the secure and unsecure urls:
both are set to: `http://www.golulo.es/`, also tryed others, like `http://golulo.es/`etc. Nothing fixed the issue.

Checked the `app/etc/local.xml` and everything seems to be correct in this format:

```
<![CDATA[usrname]]>
```

The password has `+` in it, but it worked before, so I don't think this is what causing it.

Cleared cache manually on every change I made. I can't find where is the issue?

Could anyone point me to the right dirrection?

Thanks,

Comment: You could try escaping any "bad" characters with a backslash.  Example: `*`  would be `\*`

Comment: Hey, I don't follow, where I should put the `\*` ?

Comment: Try `\+` where your password field has +

Comment: When I add this in `local.xml` I get this: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user`

Comment: I misunderstood your issue. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889286/magento-bug-illegal-scheme-supplied-only-alphanumeric-characters-are-permitte

It looks like you may have forgotten to put `http://` in your URL in the admin for the base_url.

Comment: I pointed out in the issue, that the url in the base url is set to: `http://mydomain.URI` also tryed `http://www.mydomain.URI`

Comment: Yes but double check those settings in your Configuration Scope and in the database just to be safe.  If it was working before then something must have changed.

Comment: I double checked it multiple times, and nothing works for me. I'm lost here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out what's causing it to happen, you could temporarily edit `lib/Zend/Uri.php` which is the only place in Magento that contains this error.

Around line 108 you'll find:

```
    // Security check: $scheme is used to load a class file, so only alphanumerics are allowed.
    if (ctype_alnum($scheme) === false) {
        #require_once 'Zend/Uri/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Uri_Exception('Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted');
    }
```

Add this:

```
    // Security check: $scheme is used to load a class file, so only alphanumerics are allowed.
    if (ctype_alnum($scheme) === false) {
        #require_once 'Zend/Uri/Exception.php';

     // temp code here
     echo $scheme;
     exit();
     // 

     throw new Zend_Uri_Exception('Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted');
    }
```

The next time you get it, instead of getting the Exception message you'll see the $scheme variable that's throwing the error.